# Am I missing something with exporting my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hope you can provide some fresh eyes for something I probably missed out/overlooked. 
I am currently creating a weather app with React and since adding in Navbar component, I got the error:
"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`."

However, I did export my components and imported them in index.js and app.js...I'm wondering what I possibly overlooked? Thank you for the help!

I've looked over every component created to see if I missed out on exporting any components, but they are all fine. I also checked to see if maybe I'm not importing from the right paths or folders when I try importing them, but they are fine. I'm thinking there's something either wrong with my Navbar component or App component.

```
//This is my Navbar Comp

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import SearchBox from '../SearchBox';
import UnitComponent from '../UnitComponent';

class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <ul className="navbar-container">
          <li className="navbar-list-item">
            <SearchBox />
          </li>
          <li className="navbar-list-item city-name">
            <span className="">New York,US</span>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar-list-item">
            <UnitComponent />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

```
//index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import App from './components/App';


const ROOT_NODE = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, ROOT_NODE);
```

```
//app.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../Navbar';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <span><i className="fab fa-react"></i></span>
        <span>Weather App</span>
        <span><i className="wi wi-day-sunny"></i></span>
        <Navbar />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

```
//SearchBox Component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SearchBox.css';



class SearchBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      queryString: ''
    };
  }

  handleQueryStringChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    queryString: e.target.value
  })
}

handleSearch = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Fetch weather data for:', this.state.queryString);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <form>
          <input
            type="search"
            value={this.state.queryString}
            name="searchBox"
            id="searchBox"
            placeholder="Enter City or Zipcode" />
          <span className="search-button fa fa-search"></span>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBox;
```

```
//UnitComponent

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './UnitComponent.css';

class UnitComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unit: 'C'
    };
  }

  changeUnit = (e) => {
    const newUnit = e.target.textContent;
    this.setState({
      unit: newUnit
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="unit-container">
        <span className={`unit-value ${this.state.unit === 'C' ? 'active-unit' : ''}`} onClick={this.changeUnit}>C</span>
        <span className={`unit-value ${this.state.unit === 'F' ? 'active-unit' : ''}`} onClick={this.changeUnit}>F</span>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

export default UnitComponent;


[![Folder structure][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWcyc.png
^^in each component folder, there are files such as Navbar.css, Navbar.jsx, index.js
```

Comment: Please show also SearchBox and UnitComponent, they could be causing issues also.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky ok I added it :P

Comment: If you have access to a debugger in the browser, try putting debugger statements in your render methods so you'll know when one is causing the issue, and then removing them after you've fixed the problem

Comment: Can you please share your file structure? It may be wrong import paths as @teimurjan has suggested in his answer. Is each component in a folder? Or are they all alongside `App` in the same directory in a flat structure?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky sure, I added it. For some reason the editor is acting up on me so you'll have to copy the imgur link into the search bar, sorry

Comment: Okay, last question. Each `index.js` file you, what is exactly there? Please add that to the question. Is the NavBar code you shared in the Navbar.jsx or the index.js file?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky nvm I found out the answer!! it wasn't that my paths were wrong, it's just that I neglected to import and export the modules in each index.js file per folder. it was confusing haha

Comment: You should consider posting an answer explaining what you needed to do to resolve the issue. It may help others. If you do I’d recommend sharing your original incorrect import/export as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have wrong import paths. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/84y0pmn7q9) is the demo written using your code snippets. It's working without any concerns.